# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, …) 0 non-na cases (moult package)

Tags: r

I'm new to R and don't understand much about how it works. I'm trying to run this code however the "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :  0 (non-NA) cases" constantly appears and my data actually has no NA. So what should I do?

```
> library("moult")
> 
> mym = read.csv("Test.csv", sep=";", head=T)
> head(mym)
    Age Sex  MoultPresence      Score Prim Habitat Jul.Day
1 Adult   1             1 5554210000   22   Beach     123
2 Adult   2             1 5555321000   26 Estuary     124
3 Adult   1             1 5555553200   35 Estuary     124
4 Adult   1             1 4440000000   12   Beach     126
5 Adult   2             1 5555532100   31 Mudflat     127
6 Adult   1             1 5555321000   26 Mudflat     127

> if (is.numeric(mym$Prim)) {scores <- format(mym$Prim, scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE)} else {scores <- mym$Prim}
> mscores <- substr(scores, 1, 9)
> mym$Date <- date2days(mym$Date, dateformat = "dd-mm-yyyy", startmonth = 9)
> m88.2 <- moult(Prim ~ Jul.Day, data = mym)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

> summary(m88.2)
Error in summary(m88.2) : object 'm88.2' not found

> m88c <- moult(Prim ~ Jul.Day, data = mym, type = 3)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

> summary(m88c)
Error in summary(m88c) : object 'm88c' not found

> durationmean2ab <- function(duration, mean) {
+   ab <- c(-mean/duration, 1/duration) 
+   names(ab) <- c("intercept", "slope") 
+   return(ab) 
+ }
> uz1 <- durationmean2ab(coef(m88c, "duration"), coef(m88c, "mean"))
Error in coef(m88c, "mean") : object 'm88c' not found

> 
> ssex <- ifelse(mym$Sex == 1 | mym$Sex == 3, "male", ifelse(mym$Sex == 2 | mym$Sex == 4, "female", NA))
> mym$ssex <- as.factor(ssex)
> mmf <- moult(Prim ~ Jul.Day | ssex | ssex, data = mym, type = 3)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Could any of you have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is probably going to be a bit difficult, as the `moult` package is fairly specialized. Someone will have to work through the guts of `moult` to find out what's going wrong. Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?  Alternatively, you *might* have more luck on the `r-sig-ecology@r-project.org` mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to Read the Fine Manual ... Taking a quick look at the [vignette for the moult package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moult/vignettes/moult.pdf) (emphasis added):

> `formula` can have five parts, of which the first two (`moult.index` and `days`) must always be provided:
>
> moult.index ~ days | x1 + x2 | y1 + y2 | z1
>
> On the left-hand-side of the ∼ the vector of moult indices (**between 0 and 1**, one for each
>   individual) is given, the first part after the ∼ requires a vector of corresponding days on
>   which these individuals were observed (number of days since, e.g., 1 July).

Earlier in the same document:

> This moult index can be the
>   original sum of moult scores, or some transformation of these to make the index linear... **It is convenient to scale this
>   index to range from 0 to 1.**

So I'd suggest starting with:

```
mym <- transform(mym, Prim_scaled = (Prim-min(Prim))/(max(Prim)-min(Prim)))
moult(Prim_scaled ~ Jul.Day, data = mym)
```

This appears to work OK (with moult version 1.4) with the subset of the data you've shown us:

```
mym <- read.table(header=TRUE,
                  text="
Age Sex  MoultPresence      Score Prim Habitat Jul.Day
1 Adult   1             1 5554210000   22   Beach     123
2 Adult   2             1 5555321000   26 Estuary     124
3 Adult   1             1 5555553200   35 Estuary     124
4 Adult   1             1 4440000000   12   Beach     126
5 Adult   2             1 5555532100   31 Mudflat     127
6 Adult   1             1 5555321000   26 Mudflat     127")

mym <- transform(mym, Prim_scaled = (Prim-min(Prim))/(max(Prim)-min(Prim)))
moult(Prim_scaled ~ Jul.Day, data = mym)
```

Unless you can provide a reproducible example, we probably can't get any farther.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the suggestion. Tried to transform my data but I still get the same error.

Comment: Tried to include a feather mass data and it helped but now I have another error

`> feather.mass <- c(20.4, 20.8, 21.5, 22.8, 24.4, 25.6, 26.3, 25.7, 25.7)
> mym$Prim <- ms2pfmg(mscores, feather.mass)
> mym$Date <- date2days(mym$Date, dateformat = "dd-mm-yyyy", startmonth = 9)
> m88.2 <- moult(Prim ~ Jul.Day, data = mym)
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  :   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`